# Ruby Hash/Array delete_if without a block

Tags: ruby

According to Ruby Hash/Array documentation, the `delete_if` method returns an enumerator if no block is given.  How is this useful? Can someone give an example to demonstrate this pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The enumerator will just allow you to run the block later.  For example, if you had a method that specifically handled the delete if for several different objects, you could pass it the enumerator.

In the example below, it will print **1, 3, 5**

```
arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
enumerator = arr.delete_if
enumerator.each { |el| el.even? }
puts arr.join(', ')
```

Answer (score 8):

There are some methods defined on `Enumerator` that give flexibility to iterators. One such method I often use is `with_index`.

```
p %w[a b c d e f].delete_if.with_index{|_, i| i.even?}
# => ["b", "d", "f"]
```

If this was to be done without `Enumerator` class, all kinds of methods have to be defined, including `delete_if_with_index`, and that is not a good thing.

Comment: I never thought of that before, awesome!